# Python MySQLdb script works correctly on OS X, permission denied error when copied to a linux server

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I wrote a quick python script to automate setting up wordpress blogs for friends. I've tested the script with no problems on my OS X computer, but when the script is copy pasted to a linux server and ran, the script is able to create the database, but when it tries to create the user and grant privileges to it I receive

```
"_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 
'root'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' to database 'livetest'")"
```

the script is:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="ip",  # your host
                    user="root",       # username
                    passwd="password")
                         # password


# Create a Cursor object to execute queries.
cur = db.cursor()

# Select data from table using SQL query.

cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " +blogshortstr)

cur.execute("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on " +blogshortstr +".*" + " " + "TO " +mysqluser+'@'+'ip'+ " " +'IDENTIFIED BY' + " " +mysqlpassword)

cur.execute("FLUSH PRIVILEGES")

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: It may be problem in user's privileges. MySQL has two types of user/access - local and remote. I guess, your linux server trying to access database on another host, thus it may have no access

Comment: but the exact same code connecting to the exact same mysql server with the exact same user/password works on OS X but not linux?

Comment: Because your OS X and linux systems has different ip addresses.

Comment: I set the root user to login from any IP, same problem.

Comment: Could you try first connecting via mysql client (in console, terminal) and reply with result?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured out the problem by accident thanks to another post I found thanks to a typo.

The problem turned out to be twofold.

1) When I enabled remote login it added a second root account. While the root@localhost user had the grant option, my root@ip.addr didn't. The root@ip.addr could still create and delete tables. Adding the grant option made it work.

2) At least with this code and the python module I was using (MySQLdb) nowhere is it documented in the module's documentation that the username is required to be in backticks (the key next to the 1 on QWERTY keyboard) and not regular quotes when doing GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES. I don't know why or if this is a normal thing for MySQL connectors in any language.

maybe it's obvious and I'm an idiot (this is the first thing I ever worked on in python and I've almost never used MySQL). maybe it'll help someone.